# Display characters remaining next to input/textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not great with JavaScript. I've written a small jQuery function and I've now got it working, but I just wanted to check if the code looks good or if it can be improved.

I wanted a function so that I can easily add the function to any textarea and input so that it counts characters remaining and so I can just change the max count value so I don't have to keep writing out the whole thing for every input/textarea. I want it to show the max count on focus, add a css warn class to it when it is the last 10, and add a css max-reached class to it when the count has exceeded. Here it is:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {  

    jq.fn.cmCharactersLeft = function(options) {        

        // defaults
        var defaults = {    
            maxLength: 300,
            selector: '#testform .text-count'
        }; 

        var options = jq.extend(defaults, options);     

        jq(this).keyup(function() { 

            // character length variable
            var character_length = jq(this).val().length;

            // Characters left
            if( character_length <= options.maxLength ){
               jq( options.selector ).html( options.maxLength - character_length ).removeClass('max-reached count-warn');
            }
            // Characters left last 10
            if ( character_length >= ( options.maxLength - 10 ) ){
                jq( options.selector ).html( options.maxLength - character_length ).addClass('count-warn').removeClass('max-reached');
            }
            // Max characters reached
            if ( character_length > options.maxLength ){
               jq( options.selector ).html( options.maxLength - character_length ).addClass('max-reached').removeClass('count-warn');;
            }               
        });

        // show 'characters left' on focus too
        jq(this).focus(function() {

            // character length variable
            var character_length = jq(this).val().length;

            // Characters left
            if( character_length < 1 ){
                jq( options.selector ).html( options.maxLength );
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Then I can use the above function for any textarea/input:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {  
    jq('#form1 textarea').cmCharactersLeft({
        maxLength: 50,
        selector: '#form1 .text-count'
    }); 
});

jQuery( document ).ready( function() {  
    jq('#form2 textarea').cmCharactersLeft({
        maxLength: 200,
        selector: '#form2 .text-count'
    }); 
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<textarea></textarea>
<span class="text-count"></span>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Edit**

Or, what would be a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing what `jQuery.noConflict` does.

> ```
> var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
> ```

You're using it like it creates another instance of jQuery, or something similar.

What it actually does is *relinquish control of the `$` variable.*

Due to other libraries using `$`, jQuery needs to be able to return and reset what `$` originally was.

Imagine this:

```
var $ = function(){ console.log(arguments) }; //A debugging function.

//Induction of jQuery here.

$('body'); //Returns a node containing the DOM body element.
$.noConflict();
$('body'); //Returns ['body'].
```

You're using it wrong.

---

### Using jQuery

jQuery is a framework used by many to simplify processes, but do you really need it?

An important question to ask yourself when designing / architecting a new system is whether you need a library or not.

If you're building a slick, lightning-fast mobile site, you may not have room for massive libraries like jQuery.

Luckily, people realise this and write helpful companion sites you can use like [YouMightNotNeedjQuery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Consider carefully whether it's better to write a little more code and not use jQuery, or whether it's better to lose a little performance.

---

### Bracket spacing

You shouldn't be adding spaces inside your brackets like the following example:

> ```
> jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
> ```

It should look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: I have a WordPress Website and I use plugins that use JQuery, so jquery.js is loaded on each page anyway. The reason why I used jQuery.noConflict() and replaced '$' with 'jq' was because it wasn't working without it. I followed this to fix it: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Using `jQuery` everywhere instead of `jq` should work anyway.

Comment: +1 I've never seen that "YouMightNotNeedjQuery.com" site before, thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: Notice that, instead of spelling `jQuery` everywhere, it is better to use `(function($){ [code] })(jQuery);`. and call `$`.

Comment: It's not necessarily _better_, just an alternate way of doing it. Technically, `$` is shorthand for `jQuery` anyway

Comment: True, but using `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();` isn't better in any way. Also, the wrapper function is seen a lot on plugins. That allows to remove the `defaults` variable from within `jq.fn.cmCharactersLeft()` to the top of the code, making it easier to find in case the need shows up. Also, it may be a tiny bit faster since you don't have to create that object everytime you call `jQuery('*').cmCharactersLeft()`

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference, although I'd suggest you to write an answer.